# How to get the least number of cuts to be made without bending a frame to get straight segments?

Tags: optimization, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> A locksmith has a rectangular iron frame, along with its diagonal,
> which is represented in the figure from below, and an electric grinder
> that can cut such metal. In an effort to recycle the iron, he must cut
> the structure and obtain $19$ segments of $20$ cm each. How many
> straight cuts, without bending the material, must the locksmith make
> at least?

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{3 cuts}\\
2.&\textrm{5 cuts}\\
3.&\textrm{4 cuts}\\
4.&\textrm{6 cuts}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly how to approach this question. Can someone help me here?. The only thing which I was able to spot, was the obvious lenght of $100$ cm of the diagonal. But I don't know how to connect this clue with what it is being asked.

How would I know where to get those weird cuts.

My instinct tells me to start cutting from the corners but it doesn't seem that would help much into minimizing the number of cuts to be made, therefore I'm asking for assistance. Can someone help me here?.

Which should be the way to go?. I'm not savvy with these kinds of questions so it would help me a lot if you could add a drawing or reuse my sketch to better visualize where the cuts should be made. Dashed lines or a line over the image would help.

Thus can someone help me here?.

Comment: Maybe you are allowed to cut it in half and then stack the pieces and cut them?

Comment: This is at least the fourth question about "least amount of cuts" you've posted in quick succession. Perhaps nothing carries over from one problem to the next, but I would recommend absorbing what you can learn from answers to one question before posting a similar one. Even if it doesn't 
help you solve the next problem, your problem solving ability would grow from the extra thought and digestion of information you'd put in that way.

Comment: It will be higher than 4 , so 5.